# Hadoop Pig ISO Date to Unix Timestamp

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a list of items in Pig consisting of ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) formatted date strings:

```
(2011-12-01)
(2011-12-01)
(2011-12-02)
```

Is there any way to transform these items into UNIX timestamps apart from implementing my own functions in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a UDF to do that = The good news it has already been done.
Pig also comes with "[piggybank"](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank) UDFs contributed by the community including [date convert](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/convert/package-summary.html)